# Cannot setup postgres replication in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have local kubernetes cluster where I would like to deploy primary and slave postgres instances and setup streaming replication between them. I have followed postgres documentation below to achive this:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-replication.html

Current state of things is following, slave postgres instance write following error: `database system identifier differs between the primary and standby`. I figure out that in order to fix this issue, slave postgres instance needs to use `pg_basebackup` to copy data folder from primary instance first. I did this as well and as for now I have that copy on my slave instance in the following folder `/var/lib/postgresql/main`. But, I don't understend how should I change current data folder which is placed in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and which is currently used by postgres slave postgres instance. Please advice how to deal with this. Ideally it would be greate to have this newly coppied folder in central place and reused it for all postgres instances

**UPDATE:**
I also tried to setup persistence volume and use it in the statefulset in the following way below, but in this case container does not work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-data-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /path/to/data/folder/on/my/host/machine

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

And statefulset:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: StatefulSet

spec:
  containers:    
  - name: slave-postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - name: postgres-data
      mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data

  volumes:
  - name: postgres-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: postgres-data-pvc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at your artifacts, it seems you need two persistence volumes and claims: one for `main` and the other for `standby`. You should also set the replicas to `2` in the `StatefulSet` as well.

It's best to use a Postgres operator like [Kubegres](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/kubegres-is-available-as-open-source-2197/) with full lifecycle management. You can even figure out what's missing in your artifacts from that and Just create plain YAML artifacts if you don't need other complexities of the operator.

### NOTE

Using an operator is highly recommended as it provides automatic backup and failover support. Without an operator, you would need to perform them manually.

Comment: Wow, I am really excited with you answer, thank you a lot!!! I played with this couple of days and I wasn't aware about Kubegres, looks like it is what I needed. Will check this and will back to you!

Comment: Kubegres works like a charm, thanks a lot again!

Comment: Great! 'm happy to help you!